# jQuery AJAX posting form to multiple other forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, submit, multiple-forms

I've multiple forms like these:

```
<form class="form_game">
<select name="game" class="gm">
<option value="Badminton">Badminton</option>
<option value="Basketball">Basketball</option>
<option value="Football">Football</option>
</select>
</form>

<form class="form_branch">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook_2" />
<select name="branch" id="branch" onchange="display_table();" >
<option value="CSE">CSE</option>
<option value="CE">CE</option>
<option value="ECE">ECE</option>
<option value="EE">EE</option>
<option value="IT">IT</option>
<option value="ME">ME</option>
<option value="PE">PE</option>
<option value="PG">PG</option>
</select>
</form>
<form class="form_year">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="the_ajax_hook_3" />
<select name="year" id="year" onchange="display_table_1();" >
<option value="D1">D1</option>
<option value="D2">D2</option>
<option value="D3">D3</option>
<option value="D4">D4</option>
</select>
</form>
```

My jQuery AJAX functions are:

```
function display_table(){

jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery(".form_branch").serialize(),function(response_from_display_data_table){
            jQuery(".table_disp").html(response_from_display_data_table);
        });
}
```

And

```
function display_table_1(){

jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery(".form_year").serialize(),function(response_from_display_data_table_1){
            jQuery(".table_disp").html(response_from_display_data_table_1);
        });
}
```

So as you can see that my display_table() takes value from 'form_branch' and display_table_1() from 'form_year'. And they corresponds to their respective other functions defined in jQueries.

How can I make the value from 1st form, i.e 'form_game' to pass along to both of the other forms so that other forms when submitted will post the value from 'form_game' along with their respective values to their targeted functions? What must be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [beforeSend](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) ajax event

It could be something like this (code not tested)

```
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,   jQuery(".form_branch").serialize(),function(response_from_display_data_table){
        jQuery(".table_disp").html(response_from_display_data_table);
    }).beforeSend(display_table_1());
```

or, the other way around:

```
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery(".form_year").serialize(),function(response_from_display_data_table_1){
        jQuery(".table_disp").html(response_from_display_data_table_1);
    }).beforeSend(display_table());
```

Comment: Actually I want that when user selects option from the 'form_game', the value from this form and the value he selects from the 'form_branch' will both be posted to display_data_table, i.e onchange="display_table();" is triggered.

Comment: Then you can do it like my answer but the other way around!

Comment: I'm sorry but can you write the code here. I'm just a beginner.